# Edit text hides behind on-screen keyboard

Tags: android

How can i keep my edit text floating above the on screen keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to write your activity's layout to adapt into the smaller room you will have when keyboard is up. That can be done for example including a ScrollView in your design.

Additionally, you will have to add following into your Activity's definition in the manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Now the activity's view will resize when keyboard is visible.

Comment: hi Juhani, i too having same issue and i am having tabbarview fixed at the bottom of the screen which is not part of scrollview. so if i use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" by tabbar also pushed to above the softkeypad. i dont want my softkeypad to be pushed. so can some one suggest some way to overcome from this issue.